# sql server joining table with null values with foreign key

Tags: sql-server, join, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables as below. There is a foreign key relationship between Activity and UOM tables.

```
Activity Table
ActivityID    UOMID    ProcessNam
---------------------------------------
1             2         Process1
2             1         Process2
3             null      Process3

UOM Table
UOMId         UOMText
-------------------------
   1           UOM1
   2           UOM2
```

Below is the query and result set I get

```
select a.ActivityID, u.UOMID, a.ProcessName, u.UOMText 
from Activity a
left join UOM u on a.UOMID = u.UOMId

ActivityID      UOMID       ProcessName     UOMText
1               2           Process1        UOM2
2               1           Process2        UOM1
```

Is it possible to get an additional row as below; from Activity table where UOMID is null

```
3               null        Process3        null
```

I tried to change the join as below; but the results are not changing

```
left join UOM u on a.UOMID=u.UOMId or (a.UOMID is null or u.UOMId  is
null)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Weird, your first query should produce the correct result.

Comment: There is a bit type column called IsActive in both tables and in where clause I am checking if the IsActive column true for both tables. could that be causing problem?

Comment: You're the only one who can test it. Besides, activity with NULL UOM ID would be logical to be inactive.

Comment: @RohitShanbhag, that'll be it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.ActivityID, u.UOMID, a.ProcessNam, u.UOMText 
from Activity a 
left join UOM u on a.UOMID=u.UOMId
```

returns

```
ActivityID  UOMID   ProcessNam  UOMText
1           2       Process1    UOM2
2           1       Process2    UOM1
3           NULL    Process3    NULL
```

and

```
select a.ActivityID, u.UOMID, a.ProcessNam, u.UOMText 
from Activity a 
left outer join UOM u on a.UOMID=u.UOMId where a.UOMId is not null
```

returns

```
ActivityID  UOMID   ProcessNam  UOMText
1           2       Process1    UOM2
2           1       Process2    UOM1
```